# Run multiple commands with entr

Tags: bash, shell, groff

I am attempting to use the 'entr' command to automatically compile Groff documents.

I wish to run the following line:

```sh
refer references.bib $1 | groff -ms $1 -T pdf > $2
```

Sadly it will only compile once if I try this:

```sh
echo $1 | entr refer references.bib $1 | groff -ms $1 -T pdf > $2
```

I have also tried the following, but it creates an infinite loop that cant be exited with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

```sh
compile(){
    refer references.bib $1 | groff -ms $1 -T pdf > $2
}

while true; do
    compile $1 $2
    echo $1 | entr -pd -s 'kill $PPID'
done
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/eradman/entr

Comment: Code which doesn't do what you want is a poor way to describe what you do want. What do you hope these commands should do?

Comment: I wish to automatically generate references and compile the Groff document when changes are made to the document.

Comment: The first command listed is how I would compile and generate references; I wish to use entr to automatically run that.

Comment: Thanks. Probably [edit] more details into the question itself; comments are likely to be deleted after a while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't try this because I didn't want to install `entr`. But I think the following should work:

```
echo "$1" | entr sh -c "refer references.bib $1 | groff -ms $1 -T pdf > $2"
```

Note that we run the pipe `refer | groff` in a shell to group it together. The command from your question without the shell runs `refer` upon file change, but `groff` only once. In `entr ... | groff` the `groff` part isn't executed by `entr`, but by `bash` in parallel.

This command works only if `$1` and `$2` do not contain special symbols like spaces, `*`, or `$`. The correct way to handle these arguments would be ...

```
echo "$1" | entr sh -c 'refer references.bib "$1" | groff -ms "$1" -T pdf > "$2"' . "$1" "$2"
```

Comment: @Eidolon Yes, I think `entr` interpreted the whole script as a command name. I edited the answer. Can you try again?

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, `entr` has the flag `-s` for this.

From the manual:

```
-s      Evaluate the first argument using the interpreter specified by the
        SHELL  environment  variable.   If standard output is a TTY, the name
        of the shell and exit code is printed after each invocation.
```

The updated answer to the OP's question is then

```
echo "$1" | entr -s 'refer references.bib $1 | groff -ms $1 -T pdf > $2'
```

This may have advantages such as if the original command can run in the default shell (e.g. `zsh`) without needing additional quoting of arguments (`"$1"` etc), it should run when passed to `entr` similarly well.